what is the origin of the phrase "gimme a break"?
Looking for the origins / earliest use of the phrase 'gimme a break' as meaning "come on there's no way, you're pulling my leg," or honestly any other meaning the phrase was used in as well.
Thanks so much!

The meaning is easily found, but per Etymonline, while it probably comes from cue sports (billiards of some sort), the exact origin isn't totally clear. So this seems a valid question, even if it should explain what research has been done.

@StuartF My reading of etymonline is that the billiards sense is limited to "lucky break." It's conjecture on my part, but I must assume that "gimme a break" is an extension of "short interval between spells of work"—"give me a break [from the tedium or torture of enduring your nonsense]."

It should be noted that the question is about one specific use of the phrase, not about its meaning and origin in general.

"...or honestly any other meaning the phrase was used in as well."

Christine Ammer, The American Heritage Dictionary of Idioms, second edition (2013) indicates that "give me a break" arose out of the earlier "give [someone] a break" but developed its own distinctive meaning. Here is the relevant entry from this source:

give someone a break 1. give someone a chance or special consideration. [Example omitted.] {c. 1900} ... 2. give me a break Stop trying to fool or upset or bother me. [Example omitted.] This interjection is usually uttered with semihumorous exasperation. {Slang: late 1900s} An alternative expression of exasperation is give me strength, that is, fortitude to bear or put up with something. [Example omitted.] {Colloquial, second half of 1900s}

Ammer also notes that "get a break," which is about the same age as "give someone a break," is closely allied to the latter expression—essentially the same idea from the demand side rather from the supply side.
A Google Books search turns up matches for the exact spelling "gimme a break" from as early as the late 1920s, although these occurrences involve use of the phrase in the descriptive sense of "treat me with more kindness or indulgence than you are obliged to."
A typical example from an unidentified story in The Saturday Evening Post (1929) [snippet view]:

"Don't!" he gasped. "I'm a married man! You'll kill me with that thing! Gimme a break! I'll play along with you!"
...
"My babies!" the officer whined. "They won't have a nickel, kid! Not a cent! They'll starve! Fer their sake, kid!  Gimme a break!"
"You pulled that knee trick first," Dolly panted. "I'd 'a' fought you on the level."
"I ain't kickin'," Ganvent whined. "You win. Just gimme a break. My wife ain't any too well. You'll kill me sure with that candleholder."

Ammer reports that the semi-humorous exasperation sense of "give me a break" (roughly equivalent to "lay off" or "don't be ridiculous") dates to "late 1900s." Google Books searches turn up instances well at least as early as the late 1960s.
From an unidentified article in The Stanford Quad (1969):

...John, for God's sake, call seconds....hey, let's start the meeting, all right?...wait a minute, would you, I'm, eating....gimme a break....turn it down, will you please?...the kitchen is a mess on Sunday mornings, and Sammy's not very happy about it—he's a hell of a good cook, and we don't want to lose him; but the kitchen is still dirty...God, this is a good lunch—John call seconds...okay, I need a list of those interested...may I have your attention for a second?...hey, let's quiet, down!...

From an unidentified short story in Esquire (1970):

"Larrabee? Larrabee sent it?" He folded his arms and stared into space. Ronnie was startled to see him throw his head back and burst into wild barking laughter. When he paused, his eyes wet, he looked at Ronnie and burst again into redoubled hilarity.
"Oh, Christ," he murmured, "Oh Jesus Mary and Joe. My perishing ass."
"Billy. Gimme a break. What's so goddamn funny?"

From Anthony Tuttle, Songs from the Night Before (1972):

Monday's, Tuesday's, Wednesday's, crowding Eighty-sixth Street again, why not?, Thursday's and Friday's too, only to name a few. Some of them were nice, attractive rooms, he knew the owners, wished them luck. But it was the West Side attitude prevailing again—gimme a break with "fun" singles bars,—what Larkin's had been once. With bright young "swingers," secretaries, "stewies," with gin mills with signs in their windows-SUNDAY BRUNCH/FREE BLOODY MARYS, a sure tip-off the joint was in trouble.
...
"Bad guy? You're stupid, that's all . . . Did you vote>
"Did I what?"
"The last election," Seth said. "Did you vote?"
"Gimme a break."
Seth looked at him one more time, a doctor to a patient, nodded several more times, his eyes full of judgment, and took off for the far end of the pool.

From Mark Medoff, The Kramer (1975):

MALIN. No! You don't just dictate everything!
KRAMER. That's right. Because you know better. As exhibited by the splendid job you were doing with your life before I entered it.
MALIN. Oh, Kramer, Jesus, gimme a break!
KRAMER. We'll see. See ya soon, baboon.

The evolution in meaning of "give me a break" from "do me a favor" to "don't be ridiculous" seems quite natural to me. A similar progression is evident in such kindred expressions as "oh please" and "spare me": they enter the language as earnest supplications and end (in some setting, anyway) as dismissals conveying what Ammer neatly characterizes as "semihumorous exasperation."

The spelling "gimme" may be an indication of register but it's not integral to the meaning of "give me a break" in the sense of "show me some (deserved) leniency", a meaning that is attested from early 20th century American English, as shown in the deleted answer from @user66974, or to the secondary figurative meaning offered in The American Heritage Dictionary of Idioms, (2013) cited in the answer by Sven Yargs. A paraphrase of the figurative meaning is "Ease up. It's too much 'punishment' for me", where the "punishment" can be anything the speaker finds tiresome or onerous or not to their liking, such as having to listen to more of a politician's lies, or being subjected to yet another building fire on the nightly news, or having to pay $4 for a gallon of diesel, or having to work the night shift yet again, or having to listen to  yet another dad joke, or yet another single-word request.
In other words, the secondary meaning is not an idiom at all; once "a break" had acquired the meaning of "leniency" it was just a figurative development.  "Gimme a break!" = "I don't deserve this! Let up!"
P.S. There is an elliptical usage with the figurative meaning where the speaker means "I don't deserve to be talked to in that way" which alludes to something in context; perhaps the other person is explaining something to the speaker in a manner that implies the speaker needs to be "schooled".
